# Thread control flow in async .NET Console program

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, threadpool

I was messing around with async/await in C# just to dig into some of the thread control flow and stumbled upon an unusual behavior that I would really appreciate clarification on.
It would make sense that the execution after await continues on a calling thread even if the Task itself was executed in background. And in fact that's exactly what happens with, let's say, WPF. 
The following code:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Start. Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    await Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(1000));
    Console.WriteLine($"End. Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
}
```

Results in:
Start. Thread: 1
End. Thread: 1
I realize that that's the way to make the program flow predictable etc.
But what surprised me is that the async Main method feature of .NET Console applications shows somewhat different behavior.
The same code:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Start. Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    await Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(1000));
    Console.WriteLine($"End. Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
}
```

Results in a different thread control flow:
Start. Thread: 1
End. Thread: 5
My guess is that the console application has a different concept of a synchronization context and are not bound to a main "UI" thread unlike WPF. But i'm actually struggling to find some clear info apropos of this.

Comment: Yes, you are right 
Usually it's not guaranteed to return on the same thread (which is also one of the reasons you cannot await inside a lock scope).
The default sync context for UI is different.

Comment: Yet another useful link https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/asyncawait-faq/

Comment: @Johnny Apparently the OP is after official documentation on ["*In a console application, there is no synchronization context*"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20765791/11683)

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your suggestions and info provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, When the `SynchronizationContext.Current` not is set, *(which is the case on a console application)*. The await response is invoked on the `ThreadPool`.

On a Winforms/WPF a SynchronizationContext is implemented to queue the response to either the winforms `controlToSendTo.BeginInvoke();` or the WPF `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke();`.

Reference:

- [Await, SynchronizationContext, and Console Apps](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/) (a blog post [by a member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765723/async-and-await-difference-between-console-windows-forms-and-asp-net/20765791?noredirect=1#comment98355823_20765791) of the dev team):

  > But there's one common kind of application that doesn't have a `SynchronizationContext`: console apps. When your console application's `Main` method is invoked, `SynchronizationContext.Current` will return `null`. That means that if you invoke an asynchronous method in your console app, unless you do something special, your asynchronous methods will not have thread affinity: the continuations within those asynchronous methods could end up running "anywhere."
- [Parallel Computing - It's All About the SynchronizationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/gg598924.aspx) (an article [referenced from](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) the official documentation for the `SynchronizationContext` class):

  > By default, all threads in console applications and Windows Services only have the default `SynchronizationContext`.
  >
  > ...
  >
  > Figure 4 Summary of `SynchronizationContext` Implementations
  >   ...
  >
  > ```
  > ╔═════════╦═══════════╦════════════╦════════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
  > ║         ║ Specific  ║ Exclusive  ║ Ordered    ║ Send May ║ Post May ║
  > ║         ║ Thread    ║ (Delegates ║ (Delegates ║ Invoke   ║ Invoke   ║
  > ║         ║ Used to   ║ Execute    ║ Execute    ║ Delegate ║ Delegate ║
  > ║         ║ Execute   ║ One at     ║ in Queue   ║ Directly ║ Directly ║
  > ║         ║ Delegates ║ a Time)    ║ Order)     ║          ║          ║
  > ╠═════════╬═══════════╬════════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
  > ║ ...     ║           ║            ║            ║          ║          ║
  > ╠═════════╬═══════════╬════════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
  > ║ Default ║ No        ║ No         ║ No         ║ Always   ║ Never    ║
  > ╚═════════╩═══════════╩════════════╩════════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
  > ```

Comment: You added some value @GSeg. That's great.